# How to get back to Native viewController from React Native Component in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

[Starting Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fqGZ.png)
[React Native Screen with Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUezf.png)

I want to get back to `Native viewController` from react native Component in `iOS`.

In my current project I'm implementing some of the screens with `Native code`(Obj C) and some of the screens(like which ever having the graphs and some complex dashboard UI) with React Native using `JavaScript`.

I'm  pushing the `ReactNativeObjCViewController` from `ViewConrtoller` and  loading the React Native View(Tab bar with Navigation) from `ReactNativeObjCViewController` by subclassing the `RCTRootView`.

After successful loading of React Native view and showing the proper data according to the implementation. And now I want to go back to native view i.e `ViewController` from React Native Component.

Please help me on that.

//ViewConrtoller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "ReactNativeObjCViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)moveToNext:(id)sender
{
  ReactNativeObjCViewController *rootViewController = (ReactNativeObjCViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReactNativeVC"];

  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
}
```

// ReactNativeObjCViewController.h

```
#import "ReactNativeObjCViewController.h"

#import "ReactNativeViewObjC.h"

@interface ReactNativeObjCViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ReactNativeViewObjC *reactViewWrapper;

@end

@implementation ReactNativeObjCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.title = @"React Wrapper (Obj C)";


  self.reactViewWrapper.data = [@{
                                  @"content": @"Welcome to React Native"
                                  } mutableCopy];

  [self.reactViewWrapper initializeReactView];


}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

// ReactNativeViewObjC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ReactNativeViewObjC : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *data;
- (void) initializeReactView;
@end

//ReactNativeViewObjC.m

#import "ReactNativeViewObjC.h"

#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"


@implementation ReactNativeViewObjC

-(void) initializeReactView {


  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"devdactic_tabs" initialProperties:nil
      launchOptions:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  rootView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [self addSubview:rootView];

  NSDictionary *views = @{@"rootView": rootView};
  NSArray *constraints = @[];
  constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[rootView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[rootView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

  [self addConstraints:constraints];
  [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
@end
```

/* JS files */

// index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,

} from 'react-native';


var Welcome = require('./Welcome');

var Featured = require('./Featured');

class devdactic_tabs extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'featured'
    };
  }

    render() {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS 
        unselectedTintColor="white"
                tintColor={'#c1d82f'}

        barTintColor="darkslateblue"
        selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
        title= "Featured"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
//          icon={{uri:'featured'}}
          onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                  selectedTab: 'featured',
              });
          }}>
            <Featured/>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
          title="More"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'more'}
//          icon={{uri:'contacts'}}
          onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'more',
                });
          }}>
          <Welcome/>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('devdactic_tabs', () => devdactic_tabs);
```

// Welcome.js

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,
  NavigatorIOS    
} from 'react-native';

var WelcomeView = require('./WelcomeView');

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#123456',
  }
});

class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS 
        initialRoute={{
        component:WelcomeView,
        leftButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
        title:'More',
        }}
        style={{flex:1}}
        />
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Welcome;
```

// WelcomeView.js

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

import 
{
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ListView,
    TabBarIOS,
    NavigatorIOS,
    ActivityIndicatorIOS,
    TouchableHighlight

} from 'react-native';

var BookDetails = require('./BookDetails');



    var FAKE_BOOK_DATA = [
    {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", description: "Une édition de référence des Contes de ma mère l’Oye de Charles Perrault, spécialement conçue pour la lecture sur les supports numériques. « Cependant les fées commencèrent à faire leurs dons à la princesse. La plus jeune lui donna pour don qu’elle serait la plus belle personne du monde ; celle d’après, qu’elle aurait de l’esprit comme un ange ; la troisième, qu’elle aurait une grâce admirable à tout ce qu’elle ferait ; la quatrième, qu’elle danserait parfaitement bien ; la cinquième, qu’elle chanterait comme un rossignol ; la sixième, qu’elle jouerait de toutes sortes d’instruments dans la dernière perfection. Le rang de la vieille fée étant venu, elle dit, en branlant la tête encore plus de dépit que de vieillesse, que la princesse se percerait la main d’un fuseau, et qu’elle en mourrait. » (Extrait de La Belle au Bois dormant.)", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://books.google.com/books/content?id=PCDengEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/m7G-weBZPYfnoqSiF59LIPPYOuM=/44x81/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/97/47/10974721_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/Q8IBqX3b-nhEAEYokJ_aH6jO6lE=/54x78/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/94/13/10941373_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/e3AKmyWuh1Wr4qMAM_vQ0vtN9AA=/54x77/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/94/13/10941368_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/1FxtmlxCqRb0EPdHFrFDGpZ45CE=/54x75/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/31/16/311623_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/yFgYWViboAAdHG99EoF3VULEblc=/54x74/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/97/67/10976773_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/d7ZWFBXpcaqXbOJ-W57_b8B2TR0=/54x80/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/92/85/10928519_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/d7ZWFBXpcaqXbOJ-W57_b8B2TR0=/54x80/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/92/85/10928519_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/Yttvb_8gXph4S7iJCiLQFbZ2s7Q=/54x74/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/11/00/22/11002233_ori.jpg'}}}
];

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({

});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        padding: 10
    },
    thumbnail: {
        width: 53,
        height: 81,
        marginRight: 10
    },
    rightContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginBottom: 8
    },
    author: {
        color: '#656565'
    },
    separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
    },
    listView: {
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    loading: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});

class WelcomeView extends Component{

    constructor(props){

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
               rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
           })
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        var books = FAKE_BOOK_DATA;
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(books)
    });

    }

    render(){
        return(
        <ListView 
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderBook.bind(this)}
                style={styles.listView}

            ></ListView>
        );
    }


    renderBook(book){
        return(

        <TouchableHighlight onPress= {() => this.showDetails(book)}
            underlayColor='#dddddd'>    
        <View>    
            <View style={styles.container}>

               <Image source={{uri: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}}
                style={styles.thumbnail}/>
               <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.authors}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.publisher}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}</Text>

                        </View>
               </View>

            <View style={styles.separator} />

            </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }

   showDetails(book){

       this.props.navigator.push({
            title: book.volumeInfo.title,
            component: BookDetails,
            passProps: {book}
        });
   }

}

module.exports = WelcomeView;
```

// Featured.js

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,
  NavigatorIOS,
  NativeModules

} from 'react-native';



var FeaturedList = require('./FeaturedList');

let DismissViewControllerManager = NativeModules.DismissViewControllerManager;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
});

class Featured extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: FeaturedList,
          title: 'Featured',
          leftButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
        onLeftButtonPress: () => this._handleNavigationRequest(),
        }}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      />
    );
  }


    _handleNavigationRequest() {
    DismissViewControllerManager.goBack();
  }
}

module.exports = Featured;
```

// FeaturedList.js

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
var REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:fiction';

var BookDetails = require('./BookDetails');

import {
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ListView,
    TabBarIOS,
    NavigatorIOS,
    ActivityIndicatorIOS,
    TouchableHighlight
    } from 'react-native';



var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        padding: 10
    },
    thumbnail: {
        width: 53,
        height: 81,
        marginRight: 10
    },
    rightContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginBottom: 8
    },
    author: {
        color: '#656565'
    },
    separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
    },
    listView: {
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    loading: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});

class MoreView extends Component{


    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
               rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
           })
       };
   }

    componentDidMount() {


        this.fetchData();
    }


    fetchData() {

        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.items),
                    isLoading: false
                });
            })
            .done();
    }


    render(){

         if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return this.renderLoadingView();
        }

        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderBook.bind(this)}
                style={styles.listView}
                />
        );


    }

    renderLoadingView() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.loading}>
                <ActivityIndicatorIOS
                    size='large'/>
                <Text>
                    Loading books...
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderBook(book) {
       return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress ={() => this.showBookDetails(book)} underlayColor='#dddddd'>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Image
                            source={{uri: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}}
                            style={styles.thumbnail} />
                        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.authors}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.publisher}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}</Text>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.separator} />
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
       );
   }


   showBookDetails(book){

      this.props.navigator.push({
            title: book.volumeInfo.title,
            component: BookDetails,
            passProps: {book}
        });
   }

}


module.exports = MoreView;
```

// BookDetails.js

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    ScrollView
    } from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 75,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    image: {
        width: 107,
        height: 165,
        padding: 10
    },
    description: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#656565'
    },
    scrollContainer: {
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
        padding: 10
    },
});

class BookDetails extends Component {
    render() {
        var book = this.props.book;
        var imageURI = (typeof book.volumeInfo.imageLinks !==   'undefined') ? book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : '';
        var description = (typeof book.volumeInfo.description !== 'undefined') ? book.volumeInfo.description : '';
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: imageURI}} />
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>{description}</Text>
            </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = BookDetails;
```

Comment: Did you hide your navigation bar or navigation back button, also add some screen shot of your output if possible.

Comment: Screen shots added. Please have a look

Comment: no one having answer?

Comment: is it possible to achieve with 'RCT_EXPORT_METHOD' ?